# How do I prevent my elements leaking out of my webpage?

Tags: html, css

[Screenshot sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DjHB6.png).

Whenever I reduce the resolution of the image, the cards doesn't get smaller with the page. Instead, they just stay where they are and leak out of the page. How can I make the cards get smaller with the page like all other websites? And how can I make the cards go to the next line after they get small enough?

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LemonMilkMed';
    src: url(LemonMilkMed.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'PoppinMed';
    src: url(Poppins-Medium.ttf);
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #222222;
    margin: auto;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: 'LemonMilkMed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FCFBF8;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 100;
}
 header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 5%;
    background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
    border: none;
    padding: 8px;
    background-size: 100px 90px;
    text-shadow: #a1a1a1;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }

 .Pages {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
 }

 .Pages li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 }

 .Pages li a:hover {
    color: #0082a2; 
}

.pricingbut {
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    background: #d74256;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(238, 56, 56, 0.565);
}

.pricingbut:hover {
    background: #ca3e51;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(238, 56, 56, 0.565);
}

.Pages {
    list-style: none;
    word-spacing: 25px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.Pages li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.Pages li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.Pages li a:hover {
    color: #ff6675;
}

.header h1 {
    font-family: 'LemonMilkMed';
    color: #FCFBF8;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: #a1a1a1;
}

.header {
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'PoppingMed';
    src: url(Poppins-Medium.ttf);
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');
.card-wrap {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #262626, #303030);
    background-size: 100%;
}

:root {
    --color-text: #616161;
    --color-text-btn: #eeeeee;
    --card1-gradient-color1: #f12711;
    --card1-gradient-color2: #f5af19;
    --card2-gradient-color1: #7F00FF;
    --card2-gradient-color2: #E100FF;
    --card3-gradient-color1: #3f2b96;
    --card3-gradient-color2: #a8c0ff;
    --card4-gradient-color1: #11998e;
    --card4-gradient-color2: #38ef7d;
}
.card-wrap {
    width: 220px;
    background: #262626;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #363636;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: var(--color-text);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;
    gap: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.card-wrap:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
.card-header {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    border-radius:100% 0% 100% 0% / 0% 50% 50% 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.card-header i {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 72px;
}
.card-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card-title {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}
.card-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #979797;
}
.card-btn {
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card-header.one {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--card1-gradient-color1), var(--card1-gradient-color2));
}
.card-header.two {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--card2-gradient-color1), var(--card2-gradient-color2));
}
.card-header.three {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--card3-gradient-color1), var(--card3-gradient-color2));
}
.card-header.four {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--card4-gradient-color1), var(--card4-gradient-color2));
}

.card-btn.one {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--card1-gradient-color1), var(--card1-gradient-color2));
}
.card-btn.two {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--card2-gradient-color1), var(--card2-gradient-color2));
}
.card-btn.three {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--card3-gradient-color1), var(--card3-gradient-color2));
}
.card-btn.four {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--card4-gradient-color1), var(--card4-gradient-color2));
}

.card-btn.one:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
}
.card-btn.two:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
}
.card-btn.three:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
}
.card-btn.four:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
}

#one {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 130px;
}
#two {
    margin-top: -393px;
    margin-left: 395px;
}
#three {
    margin-top: -393px;
    margin-left: 655px;
}
#four {
    margin-top: -393px;
    margin-left: 920px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <ul class="Pages">
        <li><a href="HomePage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="ContentPage.html">Content</a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutPage.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="Pricing" href="PricingPage.html"><button class="pricingbut">Pricing</button></a>
</header>

<div class="card-wrap" id="one">
    <div class="card-header one">
        <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="card-btn one">get</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card-wrap" id="two">
    <div class="card-header two">
        <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="card-btn two">get</button></a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card-wrap" id="three">
    <div class="card-header three">
        <i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="card-btn three">get</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-wrap" id="four">
    <div class="card-header four">
        <i class="fab fa-js-square"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
        <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
        <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
        <a href="#"><button class="card-btn four">get</button></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried using overflow in CSS but it didn't work, not sure if I was using it in the wrong place.

Comment: Rules like this certainly look suspect: `margin-left: 920px;`  If the container width is narrower than 920px then you're explicitly telling that element to be outside of the container.  There may be a lot more happening here, but *in general* don't use margins like this for placing things on a page.  You may be looking to research CSS flex box styling to put these "card" elements in their containing element.

Comment: How should I move the elements without using margin? And I tried removing it but it din't work the elements would still leak out. Is there a way I can resize them according to the resolution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use margins to place elements on the page:

```
#four {
    margin-top: -393px;
    margin-left: 920px;
}
```

It's basically saying, "No matter what the screen size or container limits, always put this element exactly this far from the edge."  Which of course won't take into consideration things like screen size or container limits.

Instead, put these "cards" into a containing element which uses `display: flex;` styling to arrange them dynamically.  Perhaps something like this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'LemonMilkMed';
    src: url(LemonMilkMed.ttf);
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'PoppinMed';
    src: url(Poppins-Medium.ttf);
}

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #222222;
    margin: auto;
}

li, a, button {
    font-family: 'LemonMilkMed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FCFBF8;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 100;
}
 header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 5%;
    background-color: rgb(55, 55, 55);
    border: none;
    padding: 8px;
    background-size: 100px 90px;
    text-shadow: #a1a1a1;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
 }

 .Pages {
    list-style: none;
    text-align: center;
    align-content: center;
 }

 .Pages li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
 }

 .Pages li a:hover {
    color: #0082a2; 
}

.pricingbut {
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 9px 25px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50px;
    cursor: pointer; 
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
    background: #d74256;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px rgba(238, 56, 56, 0.565);
}

.pricingbut:hover {
    background: #ca3e51;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(238, 56, 56, 0.565);
}

.Pages {
    list-style: none;
    word-spacing: 25px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.Pages li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.Pages li a {
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.Pages li a:hover {
    color: #ff6675;
}

.header h1 {
    font-family: 'LemonMilkMed';
    color: #FCFBF8;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: #a1a1a1;
}

.header {
    padding: 10px 30px;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'PoppingMed';
    src: url(Poppins-Medium.ttf);
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300;400;500;700;900&display=swap');
.card-wrap {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #262626, #303030);
    background-size: 100%;
}

:root {
    --color-text: #616161;
    --color-text-btn: #eeeeee;
    --card1-gradient-color1: #f12711;
    --card1-gradient-color2: #f5af19;
    --card2-gradient-color1: #7F00FF;
    --card2-gradient-color2: #E100FF;
    --card3-gradient-color1: #3f2b96;
    --card3-gradient-color2: #a8c0ff;
    --card4-gradient-color1: #11998e;
    --card4-gradient-color2: #38ef7d;
}
.card-wrap {
    width: 220px;
    background: #262626;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 5px solid #363636;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: var(--color-text);
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19) 0px 10px 20px,
                rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) 0px 6px 6px;
    gap: 30px;
    align-items: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
}
.card-wrap:hover {
    transform: scale(1.05);
}
.card-header {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    border-radius:100% 0% 100% 0% / 0% 50% 50% 100%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}

.card-header i {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 72px;
}
.card-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 60%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.card-title {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}
.card-text {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #979797;
}
.card-btn {
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 100px;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.card-header.one {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--card1-gradient-color1), var(--card1-gradient-color2));
}
.card-header.two {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--card2-gradient-color1), var(--card2-gradient-color2));
}
.card-header.three {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--card3-gradient-color1), var(--card3-gradient-color2));
}
.card-header.four {
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom left, var(--card4-gradient-color1), var(--card4-gradient-color2));
}

.card-btn.one {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--card1-gradient-color1), var(--card1-gradient-color2));
}
.card-btn.two {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--card2-gradient-color1), var(--card2-gradient-color2));
}
.card-btn.three {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--card3-gradient-color1), var(--card3-gradient-color2));
}
.card-btn.four {
    background: linear-gradient(to left, var(--card4-gradient-color1), var(--card4-gradient-color2));
}

.card-btn.one:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
}
.card-btn.two:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
}
.card-btn.three:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
}
.card-btn.four:hover {
    opacity: 80%;
}

#cards-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 1rem;
    padding: 1rem;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
    <ul class="Pages">
        <li><a href="HomePage.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="ContentPage.html">Content</a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutPage.html">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a class="Pricing" href="PricingPage.html"><button class="pricingbut">Pricing</button></a>
</header>
<div id="cards-container">
  <div class="card-wrap" id="one">
      <div class="card-header one">
          <i class="fas fa-code"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
          <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <a href="#"><button class="card-btn one">get</button></a>
      </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card-wrap" id="two">
      <div class="card-header two">
          <i class="fab fa-css3-alt"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
          <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <a href="#"><button class="card-btn two">get</button></a>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card-wrap" id="three">
      <div class="card-header three">
          <i class="fab fa-html5"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
          <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <a href="#"><button class="card-btn three">get</button></a>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card-wrap" id="four">
      <div class="card-header four">
          <i class="fab fa-js-square"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
          <h1 class="card-title">Title</h1>
          <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
          <a href="#"><button class="card-btn four">get</button></a>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

All I've done here is added a `<div id="cards-container">` around the four "cards" and added a style rule for that container at the end of the CSS (replacing the explicit margin styling you had for each "card").

You can adjust the styling in this container with different CSS flex options as needed.